# When I should use Rtree/KdTree vs Morton z-index and s-curves?

Tags: spatial-index, z-index, rtree

I was always confused by those two families (?) of indexing.

I feel that the first one goes with the "normal" data, while z-index and s-curves work the best for tiling/grid/uniformly distributed datasets, is that correct?